# Chrome Send Message and Listener Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have seen many similar questions, but none have solved my issue. I have a page running that has a specific div that changes every 5 seconds. I have a function in my popup.js script, which contacts my contentscript.js and asks for the value of that div. I am having a weird problem where the results from my content script on my localhost server are totally fine, but running this on the same html hosted on my domain is throwing a ***Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist, which leads to an undefined value*** . I know people said they had solutions such as disabling other extensions, but that is not a feasible solution since I plan on publishing this extension and can't force users to do that in order for it to work. I know the domain hosted on AWS works totally fine, since I can work around the website and make api calls to it through Postman etc.

popup.js

```
var currentNumber = 1000;
var lastUpdated = 1000;
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {method: "getNumber"}, function(response) {
                currentNumber = response.current;
                lastUpdated = response.lastUp;
            });
```

contentscript.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.method == "getNumber") {
            var currentNumber = document.getElementById("1MainPart_lbUsersInLineAheadOfYou").innerText;
            var lastUpdated = document.getElementById("MainPart_lbLastUpdateTimeText").innerText;
            sendResponse({current: currentNumber, lastUp : lastUpdated})
            return true;
        }
        return true;
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
 
  "name": "Extension",
  "version": "0.1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs", 
    "storage",
    "http://localhost/*", 
    "*Link to my domain*"
  ],

  "content_scripts": [{
    "js": ["contentscript.js"],
    "matches": ["http://localhost/*", "*Link to my domain*"]
  }],

  "externally_connectable": {
    "ids": [*inserted id*],
    "matches": ["*Link to my domain*"],
    "accepts_tls_channel_id": false
  },

  "background" : {
    "scripts" : ["backgroundscript.js"]
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well according to the docs under...

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#event-onMessageExternal

It says...

> onMessageExternal
>
> runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(listener: function)
>
> Fired when a message is sent from another extension/app (by
> sendMessage). **Cannot be used in a content script.**

So that only leaves a background script.

Comment: I'm not sure how it's working with my localhost server totally fine then. I can try creating a background script and putting the code into that and running it.

Comment: It can't work in a content script so if it works for you then the script is not actually a content script. For example maybe you load contentscript.js in popup.js or backgroundscript.js, in which case it won't be a content script but just a normal extension script.

Comment: I changed my contentscript.js into the background script in my manifest.json, however, it still is not working on my server. It still only works on my localhost server.